# Cookie doesn't persist between different pages on same domain

Tags: go, cookies

in part of my code i save a cookie like this

```
if encoded, err := s.Encode(USER_ID_COOKIE_NAME, value); err == nil {
            user_id := &http.Cookie{
                Name:  USER_ID_COOKIE_NAME,
                Value: encoded,
                Path:  "/",
                HttpOnly: true,
            }
            http.SetCookie(w, user_id)
        }0
```

when i do, it saves a cookie but when i try to go to another path, the cookie isnt there.

for example: once logged in, im at path "/oauth/square", when i then click on a link to "/settings" my cookie is gone. I can confirm the cookie is set while at the initial path. I've included an image of the cookie in my browser as well. How can i set the cookie so it persists anywhere while on that domain?

[image: screenshot of cookie from browser]

Comment: Your browser shows that you have set cookie for the path "/oauth/square" not "/"

Comment: I understand that. I also double checked my code and it is whats in the snippet...I don't know if your intention was meant to be helpful or not but it wasnt.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the solution was to set the Domain. once i did that everything worked as expected.